# Prove convexity of quadratic function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

g(x) = $(a^Tx - b)^2$ where a and x are n dimensional vectors and neither a nor b are a function of x. Prove that g(x) is convex.

I believe that the answer lies in taking the second derivative of g(x) w.r.t. x and prove that the quantity is greater than 0 in order to determine that g(x) is convex. I looked into using the formal definition of convexity (see link below for an example) although I don't think that is the way to go.

So I went ahead and used matrix algebra and differentiation and I arrived at:
$\frac{\partial^2 g(x)}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} (a^Tx - b)^T(a^Tx - b)$

$=  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} [aa^Tx^Tx - 2bax - b^Tb]$

$=  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} [aa^Tx^Tx - 2bax - b^Tb]$

$= 2a^Ta$

$= 2 \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 $
The sum of squares quantity is necessarily positive.

1. Am I right in using the matrix algebra and differentiation rules here?
2. Out of curiosity is there a way to prove convexity using the formal definition (link to example below)? I don't see a clean way of doing this.

[Convexity / Concavity --> Formal Definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746309/convexity-concavity-formal-definition)

Answer (score 1):

1) **About your direct formulation,**

- beware, it should be $x^Ta^Tax - 2 ba^Tx + b^Tb ;$
- moreover, instead of using the notation and concept $\partial^2/\partial x^2$ (unless you master it), you can simply consider the previous expansion

$$g(x)=b^Tb - 2 ba^Tx + x^T(a^Ta)x$$

as a Taylor expansion and identify it with

$$g(x)=g(0) + g'(0)x + \tfrac12 x^T g''(0) x $$

giving, in particular the second derivative formula:

$$\tfrac12 g''(0)=a^Ta.$$

2) **About the formal definition,** here is how it can be used.

You have to prove that, for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and any $\lambda \in [0,1]$:

$$\tag{1}g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda)g(y)$$

(1) is equivalent to:

$$\tag{2}(a^T(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) - b)^2 \leq \lambda(a^Tx - b)^2 +(1-\lambda)(a^Ty - b)^2$$

Now, in the LHS, let us write $b$ under the form $\lambda b + (1-\lambda)b$:

$$\tag{3}[a^T(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) - (\lambda b + (1-\lambda)b)]^2 \leq \lambda(a^Tx - b)^2 +(1-\lambda)(a^Ty - b)^2$$
or

$$\tag{4}[\lambda (a^T x  - b) + (1-\lambda)(a^T y  - b)]^2 \leq \lambda(a^Tx - b)^2 +(1-\lambda)(a^Ty - b)^2$$

which is a consequence of formula :

$$\tag{5}[\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v]^2 \leq \lambda u^2 +(1-\lambda)v^2,$$

valid for any $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, expressing the convexity of quadratic norm.

Comment: I have exchanged the first and second part, giving a more natural answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Jean for the clear answers. I like your note about the Taylor expansion. I think that the second derivative term should have an x^2 instead of x. The second derivative of g() w.r.t. x is 2 * a^T*a which I presume is the second derivative w.r.t. x of the formulation at the very top of your answer. So in a sense 'x^T*a^T*a*x' is synonymous with 'constant * x^2' in the 2 dimensional world where the second derivative w.r.t. x is simply 2*constant. I get it.

Comment: Yes, "$x^Ta^Tax$ is synonymous with "constant $x^2$" is the right way to see it.